# Partitioning of Integers Readability

Tags: python, integer, partition

I am working on a question about partitioning of integers. 
So far, I have been able to collect all the possible combinations, however my sets are not in a "readable" format. I have been struggling to fix this, any help is appreciated!! 
My code (in Python):

```
input = 4
maxLen = 2

def numToArray(input):
  arr = []
  for num in range(1, input+1):
    arr.append(num)
  return arr

print(numToArray(input))

def partitions(num):
    if num == 1:
        return [1]
    possiblePerms = []
    for i in range(1, num):
        possiblePerms.append([i] + partitions(num-i))
    possiblePerms.append([num])
    # print("num:", num, "possiblePerms:", possiblePerms)
    return possiblePerms

    
output = partitions(input)

for item in output:
    print(item)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "readable"?  The output I get is just wrong =) [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, [1, [1, 1], [2]], [2, 1], [3]]
[2, [1, 1], [2]]
[3, 1]
[4]

Comment: You can replace `numToArray` with `range`, but it isn't actually used in your code

Comment: @Cireo By readable, I meant that I have all the possible permutations, they are just not organized correctly. 
[3, 1] is a permutation, [4] is a permutation and then [2, 1, 1] is a permutation and [2, 2] is a permutation, etc. But you can't tell from when you look at the code because it is formatted like a tree with nested values.

Comment: I see.  You could write a second function to convert values like `[1, [[1, 1], [2]]]` into `[[1,1,1], [1,2]]`, but that logic is going to overlap significantly with what you already have

Comment: Yes, or perhaps something like array flattening?

Comment: Array flattening isn't quite enough, because you are representing choices, `[1,[[1,1],[2]]]` is quite different from `[1,1,1,2]`.  Even the depth of nesting matters, alternating between "choose from" and "a list of".

Comment: If you just want to partition efficiently, you can of course use a itertools recipe: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: Ah thank you, I will try doing that instead of what I originally did.